# Python read particular data from response JSON

Tags: python, json

I am new to Python and JSON. I am calling an API and as response body I am getting below :

```
{'product': 'Cycle', 'available': 20, 'blocked': 0, 'orderBooked': 0, 'transfer': 0, 'restock': 0, 'unavailable': 0, 'total': 0, 'lCode': '2000112', 'locationId': '745', 'locationCode': '425', 'stockType': 'IN STOCK', 'adminStock': {'rp': 0, 'management': 0, 'rc': 0, 'total': 0, 'default': 0}, 'isBlocked': False, 'plannedDate': None, 'plannedUpdate': True, 'bookedQuantity': 0}
{'product': 'Cooker', 'available': 958, 'blocked': 10, 'orderBooked': 10, 'transfer': 30, 'restock': 0, 'unavailable': 0, 'total': 0, 'lCode': '589620', 'locationId': '420', 'locationCode': '695', 'stockType': 'PRE ORDER', 'adminStock': {'rp': 0, 'management': 0, 'rc': 0, 'total': 0, 'default': 0}, 'isBlocked': False, 'plannedDate': None, 'plannedUpdate': True, 'bookedQuantity': 0}
{'product': 'Cycle', 'available': 96220, 'blocked': 0, 'orderBooked': 0, 'transfer': 0, 'restock': 0, 'unavailable': 0, 'total': 0, 'lCode': '2000112', 'locationId': '745', 'locationCode': '425', 'stockType': 'CONFIRMED', 'adminStock': {'rp': 0, 'management': 0, 'rc': 0, 'total': 0, 'default': 0}, 'isBlocked': False, 'plannedDate': None, 'plannedUpdate': True, 'bookedQuantity': 0}
{'product': 'Lapms', 'available': 89958, 'blocked': 1890, 'orderBooked': 1045, 'transfer': 230, 'restock': 0, 'unavailable': 0, 'total': 0, 'lCode': '78963', 'locationId': '896', 'locationCode': '463', 'stockType': 'TRANSIT', 'adminStock': {'rp': 0, 'management': 0, 'rc': 0, 'total': 0, 'default': 0}, 'isBlocked': False, 'plannedDate': None, 'plannedUpdate': True, 'bookedQuantity': 0}
```

The data I mentioned above will vary as per the API request. So Whatever be the response. Based on the Products, I need to Print Multi line data. My request is to read this Json and get the following Data :

```
Name:<'product'>, Code:<'lCode'>, Location:<'locationCode'>, Stock Type:<'stockType'>, Availability:<'available'>
```

So For the Above Json, the output should be like :

```
Name:Cycle, Code:2000112, Location:425, Stock Type:PRE ORDER, Availability:20
Name:Cooker, Code:589620, Location:695, Stock Type:<'stockType'>, Availability:958
Name:Cycle, Code:2000112, Location:425, Stock Type:CONFIRMED, Availability:96220
Name:Lapms, Code:78963, Location:463, Stock Type:TRANSIT, Availability:89958
```

So Based on the Times,

> product is occuring, the data output will be having that much lines

I dont have any idea on parsing Json in Python. Please help in understanding how I can get the data in below format. I havent tried anything as I am stuck

Comment: What are you trying to do? Store each row? Parse the row and add each field to a list?

Comment: you are already getting it as a json. 
Read it directly into a dict. and access using the key.

Comment: @EvanLalo I need to read this Json and Print the data in the format i mentioned as a single line

Comment: Right, but does each key in the format you have contain a single item, or all of the appropriate items from the response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I believe you want. As some comments say, indeed these outputs should be treated as dictionaries or lists, with dictionaries and/or lists nested within them. It's important to know the difference since the first should be addressed by its `key` whereas the latter by its `index`. You can find some extra information regarding how to read jsons/dictionaries [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57875259/how-to-extract-nested-json-data/57875343#57875343)

```
import pandas as pd
json_1 = {'product': 'Cycle', 'available': 20, 'blocked': 0, 'orderBooked': 0, 'transfer': 0, 'restock': 0, 'unavailable': 0, 'total': 0, 'lCode': '2000112', 'locationId': '745', 'locationCode': '425', 'stockType': 'IN STOCK', 'adminStock': {'rp': 0, 'management': 0, 'rc': 0, 'total': 0, 'default': 0}, 'isBlocked': False, 'plannedDate': None, 'plannedUpdate': True, 'bookedQuantity': 0}
json_2 = {'product': 'Cooker', 'available': 958, 'blocked': 10, 'orderBooked': 10, 'transfer': 30, 'restock': 0, 'unavailable': 0, 'total': 0, 'lCode': '589620', 'locationId': '420', 'locationCode': '695', 'stockType': 'PRE ORDER', 'adminStock': {'rp': 0, 'management': 0, 'rc': 0, 'total': 0, 'default': 0}, 'isBlocked': False, 'plannedDate': None, 'plannedUpdate': True, 'bookedQuantity': 0}
json_3 = {'product': 'Cycle', 'available': 96220, 'blocked': 0, 'orderBooked': 0, 'transfer': 0, 'restock': 0, 'unavailable': 0, 'total': 0, 'lCode': '2000112', 'locationId': '745', 'locationCode': '425', 'stockType': 'CONFIRMED', 'adminStock': {'rp': 0, 'management': 0, 'rc': 0, 'total': 0, 'default': 0}, 'isBlocked': False, 'plannedDate': None, 'plannedUpdate': True, 'bookedQuantity': 0}
json_4 = {'product': 'Lapms', 'available': 89958, 'blocked': 1890, 'orderBooked': 1045, 'transfer': 230, 'restock': 0, 'unavailable': 0, 'total': 0, 'lCode': '78963', 'locationId': '896', 'locationCode': '463', 'stockType': 'TRANSIT', 'adminStock': {'rp': 0, 'management': 0, 'rc': 0, 'total': 0, 'default': 0}, 'isBlocked': False, 'plannedDate': None, 'plannedUpdate': True, 'bookedQuantity': 0}
support_list = []
support_list.append([json_1,json_2,json_3,json_4])
support_dict = {'Name':[],'Code':[],'Location':[],'Stock type':[],'Availability':[]}

for i in range(len(support_list[0])):
    support_dict['Name'].append(support_list[0][i]['product'])
    support_dict['Code'].append(support_list[0][i]['lCode'])
    support_dict['Location'].append(support_list[0][i]['locationCode'])
    support_dict['Stock type'].append(support_list[0][i]['stockType'])
    support_dict['Availability'].append(support_list[0][i]['available'])
df = pd.DataFrame(support_dict)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     Name     Code Location Stock type  Availability
0   Cycle  2000112      425   IN STOCK            20
1  Cooker   589620      695  PRE ORDER           958
2   Cycle  2000112      425  CONFIRMED         96220
3   Lapms    78963      463    TRANSIT         89958
```

### EDIT: OPs says it's only list with multiple jsons in it.

It applies the same logic:

```
import pandas as pd
json_output= [{'product': 'Cycle', 'available': 20, 'blocked': 0, 'orderBooked': 0, 'transfer': 0, 'restock': 0, 'unavailable': 0, 'total': 0, 'lCode': '2000112', 'locationId': '745', 'locationCode': '425', 'stockType': 'IN STOCK', 'adminStock': {'rp': 0, 'management': 0, 'rc': 0, 'total': 0, 'default': 0}, 'isBlocked': False, 'plannedDate': None, 'plannedUpdate': True, 'bookedQuantity': 0},{'product': 'Cooker', 'available': 958, 'blocked': 10, 'orderBooked': 10, 'transfer': 30, 'restock': 0, 'unavailable': 0, 'total': 0, 'lCode': '589620', 'locationId': '420', 'locationCode': '695', 'stockType': 'PRE ORDER', 'adminStock': {'rp': 0, 'management': 0, 'rc': 0, 'total': 0, 'default': 0}, 'isBlocked': False, 'plannedDate': None, 'plannedUpdate': True, 'bookedQuantity': 0},{'product': 'Cycle', 'available': 96220, 'blocked': 0, 'orderBooked': 0, 'transfer': 0, 'restock': 0, 'unavailable': 0, 'total': 0, 'lCode': '2000112', 'locationId': '745', 'locationCode': '425', 'stockType': 'CONFIRMED', 'adminStock': {'rp': 0, 'management': 0, 'rc': 0, 'total': 0, 'default': 0}, 'isBlocked': False, 'plannedDate': None, 'plannedUpdate': True, 'bookedQuantity': 0},{'product': 'Lapms', 'available': 89958, 'blocked': 1890, 'orderBooked': 1045, 'transfer': 230, 'restock': 0, 'unavailable': 0, 'total': 0, 'lCode': '78963', 'locationId': '896', 'locationCode': '463', 'stockType': 'TRANSIT', 'adminStock': {'rp': 0, 'management': 0, 'rc': 0, 'total': 0, 'default': 0}, 'isBlocked': False, 'plannedDate': None, 'plannedUpdate': True, 'bookedQuantity': 0}]
support_dict = {'Name':[],'Code':[],'Location':[],'Stock type':[],'Availability':[]}

for i in range(len(json_output)):
    support_dict['Name'].append(json_output[i]['product'])
    support_dict['Code'].append(json_output[i]['lCode'])
    support_dict['Location'].append(json_output[i]['locationCode'])
    support_dict['Stock type'].append(json_output[i]['stockType'])
    support_dict['Availability'].append(json_output[i]['available'])
df = pd.DataFrame(support_dict)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     Name     Code Location Stock type  Availability
0   Cycle  2000112      425   IN STOCK            20
1  Cooker   589620      695  PRE ORDER           958
2   Cycle  2000112      425  CONFIRMED         96220
3   Lapms    78963      463    TRANSIT         89958
```

### EDIT 2: If you want the output as lines:

```
json_output= [{'product': 'Cycle', 'available': 20, 'blocked': 0, 'orderBooked': 0, 'transfer': 0, 'restock': 0, 'unavailable': 0, 'total': 0, 'lCode': '2000112', 'locationId': '745', 'locationCode': '425', 'stockType': 'IN STOCK', 'adminStock': {'rp': 0, 'management': 0, 'rc': 0, 'total': 0, 'default': 0}, 'isBlocked': False, 'plannedDate': None, 'plannedUpdate': True, 'bookedQuantity': 0},{'product': 'Cooker', 'available': 958, 'blocked': 10, 'orderBooked': 10, 'transfer': 30, 'restock': 0, 'unavailable': 0, 'total': 0, 'lCode': '589620', 'locationId': '420', 'locationCode': '695', 'stockType': 'PRE ORDER', 'adminStock': {'rp': 0, 'management': 0, 'rc': 0, 'total': 0, 'default': 0}, 'isBlocked': False, 'plannedDate': None, 'plannedUpdate': True, 'bookedQuantity': 0},{'product': 'Cycle', 'available': 96220, 'blocked': 0, 'orderBooked': 0, 'transfer': 0, 'restock': 0, 'unavailable': 0, 'total': 0, 'lCode': '2000112', 'locationId': '745', 'locationCode': '425', 'stockType': 'CONFIRMED', 'adminStock': {'rp': 0, 'management': 0, 'rc': 0, 'total': 0, 'default': 0}, 'isBlocked': False, 'plannedDate': None, 'plannedUpdate': True, 'bookedQuantity': 0},{'product': 'Lapms', 'available': 89958, 'blocked': 1890, 'orderBooked': 1045, 'transfer': 230, 'restock': 0, 'unavailable': 0, 'total': 0, 'lCode': '78963', 'locationId': '896', 'locationCode': '463', 'stockType': 'TRANSIT', 'adminStock': {'rp': 0, 'management': 0, 'rc': 0, 'total': 0, 'default': 0}, 'isBlocked': False, 'plannedDate': None, 'plannedUpdate': True, 'bookedQuantity': 0}]

for i in range(len(json_output)):
    print('Name: ' + str(json_output[i]['product']) + ', Code: ' + str(json_output[i]['lCode']) + ', Location: ' + str(json_output[i]['locationCode']) + ', Stock type: ' + str(json_output[i]['stockType']) + ', Availability: ' + str(json_output[i]['available']))
```

Output:

```
Name: Cycle, Code: 2000112, Location: 425, Stock type: IN STOCK, Availability: 20
Name: Cooker, Code: 589620, Location: 695, Stock type: PRE ORDER, Availability: 958
Name: Cycle, Code: 2000112, Location: 425, Stock type: CONFIRMED, Availability: 96220
Name: Lapms, Code: 78963, Location: 463, Stock type: TRANSIT, Availability: 89958
```

Comment: Its not as seperate Jsons. Its just one json

Comment: Then you should format it correctly as a list, separated by commas.

Comment: Check after the edit, still your json is poorly formatted and should be fixed

Comment: Its works fine, instead of table, can we make it as multiple sentence.

Comment: Of course, I'll edit it and if it works fine for you, you can upvote it and accept to make this answer more visible for other people with similar issues.

Comment: Done. Thanks for the help. Very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you parse json file you will get standard python dictionary.

```
import json

json_data = '{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3, "d": 4, "e": 5}'
parsed_json = (json.loads(json_data))
```